# Undefined Method with a method that shouldnt be a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I was trying to run this set of code in ruby on rails with html and css embedded:

```
<h2>Edit User Account</h2>

<form action="/update_Template/<%= @Template.id %>">
  <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="url" value="<%= @Template.url %>">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value="<%= @Template.name %>">
  <input type="text" name="member" placeholder="member" value="<%= @Template.member %>">
  <input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="caption" value="<%= @Template.caption %>">
  <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="location" value="<%= @Template.location %>">
  <input type="text" name="bar" placeholder="bar" value="<%= @Template.bar %>">
  <input type="text" name="bar1" placeholder="bar1" value="<%= @Template.bar1 %>">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

However, I keep getting this syntax error message whenever I try to load the page:

```
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

With This line highlighted:

```
 <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="url for your template" value="<%= @Template.url %>">
```

I have tried to change it in every way I could and searched up some other problems people have had like this, but so far I cant find what I am doing wrong. Thanks for reading and if you do reply.

Comment: @Template is probably not defined in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your @Template was not set in controller edit action or wherever you set it. Also, you should not use capital letters as a first letter of a variable. By convention capital letters indicate class names and such.